# Python exit code not capturing in control-m

Tags: python, python-3.x, jobs, job-scheduling, control-m

Running python code through Control-M Jobs.If below code exit with status 7 in python. Control-m should capture code and on do Action if status 7 then code should set As Ok and should mail through Control-m.

```
try:
   fh = open("testfile", "r")
   fh.write("This is my test file for exception handling!!")
except IOError:
   print "Error: can\'t find file or read data"
   exit(7)
```

Code is terminating with exit status 7 but in control-m not able to capture exit status.
In Control-m, On do Action i added if status 7 then Job should Set As Ok and should send mail.

Can someone help me how Control-M can capture Python code exit status?

Comment: Try to replace the `exit(7)` with `sys.exit(7)` (don't forget to `import sys`)

Comment: yes it is working

Answer (score 2):

The working code would look like this (based on Amiram's comment)

```py
import sys

try:
   fh = open("testfile", "r")
   fh.write("This is my test file for exception handling!!")
except IOError:
   print "Error: can\'t find file or read data"
   sys.exit(7)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run script with bashscript and echo exitcode of python script.